# Uncategorized SQL Exception while calling stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc, ojdbc

I'm trying to call a stored procedure with JDBC to an Oracle database, but I have a couple of issues.

SQL package definition with stored procedure to call

```
create or replace PACKAGE PACK AS
 
 TYPE type_rec IS RECORD (
  module    VARCHAR2(40),
  value     VARCHAR2(80),
  message   VARCHAR2(4000));

 TYPE type_msg_array IS VARRAY(250) OF type_rec;

PROCEDURE FUNC (
  provco            IN  VARCHAR2,
  id             IN  VARCHAR2,
  code         OUT NUMBER,
  msg               OUT VARCHAR2,
  msg_array       IN OUT type_msg_array);
END PACK;
```

Main method that creates the request and calls the stored procedure

```
public Map<String, Object> executeFunc(final String db, final RequestPojo request) {
    Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> funcOutput = null;
    
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate(db).getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());
    
    MessagePojo message = new MessagePojo();
    List<MessagePojo> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    messageList.add(message);
    
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>(messageList);
    
    try (final Connection connectionWrapper = jdbcCall.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection()){
        buildFuncParameters(jdbcCall, inParamMap, request);

        inParamMap.put("msg_array", new ScriptArray(objectList, connectionWrapper));

        funcOutput = jdbcCall.execute(inParamMap);

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        throw new DataRetrievalFailureException(sqlEx.getMessage());
    }
    
    return funcOutput;
}
```

Helping method that builds the request

```
private void buildFuncParameters(SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall, Map<String, Object> inParamMap, RequestPojo request) {
    jdbcCall.withCatalogName("PACK");
    jdbcCall.withProcedureName("FUNC");
    
    jdbcCall.declareParameters(
            new SqlParameter("provco", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("id", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlOutParameter("code", Types.NUMERIC),
            new SqlOutParameter("msg", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlInOutParameter("msg_array", java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "PACK".concat(".TYPE_MSG_ARRAY"))
            );
    jdbcCall.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
    jdbcCall.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false);
    jdbcCall.withReturnValue();
    
    inParamMap.put("provco", findCritSeqRequest.getProvco());
    inParamMap.put("id", findCritSeqRequest.getId());
}
```

ScriptArray utility class

```
public class ScriptArray extends AbstractSqlTypeValue {
    private List<Object> values;
    private Connection oracleConnection;
    
    public ScriptArray(List<Object> values, final Connection oracleConnection) {
        this.values = values;
        this.oracleConnection = oracleConnection;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTypeValue(Connection con, int sqlType, String typeName)
            throws SQLException {
       return oracleConnection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class).createARRAY(typeName, values.toArray(new Object[values.size()]));
    }

}
```

After the execution, I get the following error

```
ERROR org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call PACK.FUNC(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17074]; invalid name pattern: PACK.TYPE_MSG_ARRAY; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: PACK.TYPE_MSG_ARRAY
```

Hope you can help me out on this one.

Comment: Do you understand some of the exception message?

Comment: I've tried many things about the invalid name pattern, some said that about making it uppercase but it wasn't my case.

Comment: What Oracle documentation have you been looking at to get this far?